# What is the period of time that the window manager waits before marking a window as unresponsive?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-xp, dwm

How long does windows wait before deciding a window is unresponsive and brings up the the unresponsive chrome?  Just from anecodotal experience, I assume it is different in XP and Vista, as they are handled very differently by the DWM in Vista and the Explorer shell in XP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from [Windows Error Reporting at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513616(VS.85).aspx)

> An application is considered
>   unresponsive (or hung) if it does not
>   respond to Windows messages for five
>   seconds and the user is trying to
>   interact with the application.

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember reading about a 5 second wait after the application has stopped fetching messages from the message queue before windows labels the app as unresponsive. I will try to post a link if I ever find that article again :)

Answer (score 0):

It is based more on the number of outstanding items in the message queue than a time interval.